# Heroku Procfile with multiple workers

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, heroku

I have an app with 1 web dyno, 7 background queues, and 1 clock. I want to use the Heroku Standard 1x plan as it includes unlimited background workers (and the number of queues might increase further in the future). When I deploy my app, the procfile doesn't appear to provision the way I expected. Three dynos are shown, and it looks like I have to purchase an additional Standard 1x dyno for each worker/clock.

Procfile:

```
web: flask db upgrade; gunicorn webapp:app
worker: rq worker -u $REDIS_URL high default low
worker: rq worker -u $REDIS_URL r1
worker: rq worker -u $REDIS_URL r2
worker: rq worker -u $REDIS_URL bg1
worker: rq worker -u $REDIS_URL bg2
worker: rq worker -u $REDIS_URL bg3
worker: rq worker -u $REDIS_URL bg4
clock: python clock.py
```

Heroku shows 3 dynos:

- 1x web (enabled, scale:1, Standard 1x)
- 1x worker "bg4" (scale:0)
- 1x clock (scale:0)

How should I structure the Procfile to take advantage of the background workers included in the Standard 1x dyno?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there was an error in how I structured the procfile. Each "worker" should be named differently. I thought the term "worker" held some special meaning for Heroku provisioning; it doesn't. So Procfile should look something like this:

```
web: flask db upgrade; gunicorn webapp:app
worker1: rq worker -u $REDIS_URL high default low
worker2: rq worker -u $REDIS_URL r1
worker3: rq worker -u $REDIS_URL r2
worker4: rq worker -u $REDIS_URL bg1
foo_worker5: rq worker -u $REDIS_URL bg2
more_worker6: rq worker -u $REDIS_URL bg3
another_worker7: rq worker -u $REDIS_URL bg4
clock: python clock.py
```

Secondly, the answer to my actual question (thanks to Heroku support team) is that a seperate Dyno is required for each additional worker process. I feel how it's phrased on the Heroku pricing page is a little missleading.

[image: Heroku Standard pricing as of May 2021]

The support team were able to clarify:

> In this context, "unlimited background workers" means you can run as
> many worker processes as you need to. On the lower tiers(free and
> hobby), the number of worker processes that can be used is limited.
>
> However, Heroku is built on a 1-process-per-dyno model, which means
> every worker needs to run on its own dyno. So you will be charged for
> 1 dyno for each worker process you use. To say it a different way,
> it's not "unlimited worker processes for $25/mon", but instead it's
> "run unlimited worker processes at $25/mon each".

Basically, the Free tier can have up to 2 dynos, Hobby can have up to 10 and the Production tiers can have as many as you want.